# Настройка фильтра авторизации mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Хочу настроить фильтр для доступа к админ странице, таким образом:

```
[Authorize(Roles="Administrators")]
public class AdminController : Controller
{        
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Я использую Identity(без EF) с реализацией своих классов User и Role.
И где-то видимо я что-то недопонимаю. В БД в таблице UserRole у меня есть сопоставление моего пользователя с ролью "Administrators". Пользователь проходит процесс аутентификации (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated = true) Вопрос в следующем, наверно очень глупый, не обессудьте:

```
@await UserManager.IsInRoleAsync(UserInfo, "Administrators");
// вернет true, UserInfo (мой класс User)

@User.IsInRole("Administrators")
// вернет false
```

Я так понимаю что это разные вещи, а как то это можно сопоставить, чтобы можно было использовать фильтр [Authorize(Roles="Administrators")] или по другому защитить страницу ? Направьте плиз в верном направлении.

Comment: может быть Вам поможет эта [ссылка](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/8.3.php)

Comment: @Bald, спасибо, создать свой фильтр авторизации конечно неплохо, но думаю пока рано) у меня ощущение что я забыл где-то что-то указать/подключить.

Comment: Помогла ссылка https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53271496/asp-net-core-identity-2-user-isinrole-always-returns-false Возможно кому-нибудь поможет тоже.